# Xpath for button having text as 'New'

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In our application almost in every screen we have a button with text 'New', Here is the html source for one of the button:

```
<button id="defaultOverviewTable:j_id54" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-hover" type="submit" name="defaultOverviewTable:j_id54" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">New</span>
</button>
```

I have tried using the below statement to click on the button:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[[@type, 'submit'] and [text()='New']]")).click();
```

But this was not working

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector //button[[@type= 'submit'] and [text()='New']] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.
```

Currently I am using the below code to click on the button:

```
List<WebElement> allButt = driver.findElements(By.tagName("button"));
for (WebElement w : allButt)
{
    if (w.getText().matches("New"))
    {
        w.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

As I have almost 150 buttons in the page. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Your xpath syntax is wrong - you don't need the inner set of square brackets - but even if you fix this:

```
//button[@type, 'submit' and text()='New']
```

it won't select what you want it to. The problem is that the "New" is not text contained directly in the button element but is inside a child span element. If instead of `text()` you just use `.` then you can check the whole string value of the element (the concatenation of all descendant text nodes at whatever level)

```
//button[@type='submit' and contains(., 'New')]
```

Or check `span` instead of `text()`:

```
//button[@type='submit' and span='New']
```

(submit buttons containing a span whose value is "New")

Comment: You could also use the path to the `span` containing the text inside the predicate.

Answer (score 10):

Try this xpath instead:

```
//button[@type='submit']/span[.='New']
```

**Demo**

http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ff393b48183ee3f373d4ca5f539bedf2

---

**EDIT**

Following comment from [@Ian Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592139/ian-roberts), you can use the following xpath expression instead if the click on the button element is important:

```
//button[@type='submit']/span[.='New']/..
```

Comment: Technically this will end up clicking the `span` rather than the `button` but the event will bubble up so it will have the required effect.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thks for your comment ;)

Answer (score 3):

The very simple solution for the above issue is to use span with option `contains(text(),'')`.

You can use the following xpath code

```
//span[contains(text(),'New')]
```